# python 2: calculate using user defined/named variables

Tags: python, python-2.7

is it possible to create variables with user defined names/values
and then let the user use operations to calculate using them?

I tried using dictionaries, but I want the user to be able to just input 
something like key1_name + key2_name and then return the output of a chosen operation

So for example:
Have the user enter 2 variables, with the names he chose,
then let the user be input an operation using the names and return the result

```
numbers = {}
numbers['1'] = 50
numbers['2'] = 100
numbers['efg'] = 200
```

how can I create a function, where I let the user input for example 1+2+efg, or 2*efg*2+1 and then return it the
result of the operation?

could I let the user for example input efg*10 and then let the function return the result of numbers['efg']*10

i tried this exmaple to make my question clearer
so this works, if I input something like name['chosenname']*10 as the operation and it returns the correct result
How can I get it to work using an input, like chosenname*10, where the user has to input only the key name ?

```
numbers = {}
name = raw_input('name')
value = input('value')
numbers[name] = value

operation = input('operation')
print operation
```

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the inputted variables to use the `numbers` dictionary with [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html).

```
import re
...
operation = raw_input('operation')
operation = re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)', r'numbers["\1"]', operation)
result = eval(operation)
print result
```